# I want to make a Drupal 8 view with contextual filter

Tags: views, 8

I want to make an intelligent view and want to pass contextual filter. If the contextual filter value is passed in the url so only display the article having the id like `http://example.com/article/2`. So show only the node with the id 2. And If the id not pass so`(http://example.com/article/)` show all the articles. 
I can do this by creating 2 views **but I want all this in a single view**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Goto **admin/structure/views/add** and add a view like below:

[image]

After adding view, go to view edit page and Under "ADVANCED", select "Contextual filters", and add "Content: Id". Under "WHEN THE FILTER VALUE IS NOT IN THE URL" check "Display all results for the specified field". In the same block, under "Exceptions", Exception value should be null. Check below image.

[image]

Now if you go to http://example.com/article you will see all the articles. And go to http://example.com/article/123 you will see related article.

Comment: Thanks Ajay I am really thank full to you. You are really a kind and humble person. God Bless you.